# Helping someone improve or helping someone to improve?

Tags: difference, verbs

Someone asked me today if the correct way to say it is the former or the latter, and I realized I have no idea if there is a preferable one, and if so, why. I always use 'helping improve' like in 'im helping someone improve their cooking skills', but I couldn't explain why if asked. Is one better than the other or could I say either just fine?